# The details of D3 Sankey diagram nodes positioning Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I think I need more explanation about the sankey graph's node positioning algorithm. From this page http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/, I know that it is iterative relaxation that is used in D3's plugin sankey.js to determine the nodes vertical positions so as to minimize the link distance. But to the best of my knowledge, iterative relaxation is usually leveraged to solve equation Ax=b. For the nodes positioning problem here, if the x is the nodes' y(vertical)  coordinates, what's the A　and b?

Comment: Have you made any progress in minimizing link crossing?